# Redirecting with javascript after adding googlemap location to sql database

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, google-maps

I'm quite new to javascript (okay, I've spent only two days using it!). One of the things I want to do on my site is allow users to add a marker to a google map. I've been reading up on the googlemaps API the last couple of days and used one of the tutorials ( https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3) and edited it for my needs. The latitude and longitude of the markers are passed into a SQL database using javascript. When I check the database, I can see that the markers have been added, which is great, but there's no way of knowing if it has been successful from the user end. When I click the 'submit' button, the data is passed into the database but I would like to then redirect to another page, or display a message that it has been successful.

The code is:

```
var marker;

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  var options = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
});
}

  function saveData() {
  var latlng = marker.getPosition();

  var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?lng=" + latlng.lng() + "&lat=" + latlng.lat();

  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
       if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
     window.navigate('index.html')
    }
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="container">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 938px; height: 600px">
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<table>
<tr><td><input type='button' value='Save Marker' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I deleted some of the unnecessary stuff from there. The problem seems to lie in 'window.navigate' part, but much searching hasn't got me any further.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your line

```
window.navigate('index.html')
```

So change it to:

```
window.navigate("index.html");
```

notice the addition of the semi-colon.

2) Use this instead as this works in all browsers:

```
window.location.href = '...';
```

Anyway the first thing to do is to check that your if statement is actually being executed. So print something out to the browser instead of redirecting to another page. If nothing is printed then you know your if statement is not even being executed. Then what you can do is check the variables that require the if statement to be executed. So you can print the data variable out to the browser before testing the if statement and seeing whether the condition is true. in your case the data.length needs to be <1... so print out the data variable before and make sure that it is less than one... if not then you know why your if statement is not being executed and therefor knowing why your web page isnt being redirected!

Comment: I don't think the semicolons are necessary in that case. They are not expression terminators, they are expression separators.

Comment: and finally if that doesnt work your if statement is not being executed hence the web browser is not actually navigating you to your desired location - index.html.

what I also suggest you do after you've fixed the basic errors if all else fails, is to make sure your sql query actually worked.

Before executing your if statement..... in javascript print the data variable out to the browswer so you can see whats inside.. and actually check whether data.length is less than one because thats the only way your if statement is allowed to execute otherwise you know why it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is return a success code if the marker is successfully added (in phpsqlinfo_addrow.php) like so:

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO .....")){
    //Success
    echo 1;
} else{
    //Failed
    echo 2;
}
```

And then in your ajax call you can check if it was added succesfully like so:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;

        var response = request.responseText;

        if(response == 1){
            //success
            callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        } else{
            //failed
            alert('something went wrong!');
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe you could use the `downloadUrl` function he used to show how it works

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of Terwanerik:

```
downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data == "1") {
        //success
        window.navigate('index.html')
    } else{
        //failed
        alert('something went wrong!');
    }
  }
});
```

You should change the phpsqlinfo_addrow.php file to match what he said:

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO .....")){
  //Success
  echo 1;
} else{
  //Failed
  echo 2;
}
```